# Server throws LimitInternalRecursion error when using htacess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

I'm quite new to `.htaccess` and I just didn't get into it enough to understand what's going on. The server just says, limit of 10 internal redirects exceeded even though I can't see any reason for it to "redirect". It only happens when I try to use `/users/Username`, `/users/` shows an error that this user can't be found which is like I wanted it, `/users/Username` throws a 500 Internal Server Error. The document itself is fine, the database check should also work. The `.htaccess` document is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

IndexIgnore * 

ErrorDocument 400     /
ErrorDocument 404     /

RewriteRule    ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ users.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: `I can't see any reason for it to "redirect"` - It's an _internal_ redirect, or more often referred to as an _internal rewrite_. This is exactly what you are doing when you "redirect" to `users.php?id=$1` etc. Do you have any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files? Which Apache version? From the code you've posted it's not obvious why you are getting a rewrite loop. In fact, the code you posted wouldn't match a request for `/users/` (no username) so how is this being routed? Do you have a physical directory called `/users`?

Comment: No, no physical /users/, no other htaccess, no nothing. All it is is users.php and this htaccess provided above. And yea I know it is an internal rewrite but I can't see the reason why this document should generate 10 of them

Comment: What does Apache error log show?

Comment: Get more debug info with `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
> RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
> :
> RewriteRule    ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ users.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
> ```

The first rule block is catching a request for `/users/Username`. In this instance, `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `.../users` (the first whole path segment after a valid directory) and `.../users.php` is indeed a valid file in this case. However, you are appending `.php` onto the end of the requested URL, so `/users/Username` becomes `/users/Username.php`, `/users/Username.php.php`, etc.

You can get around this conflict by simply reversing the order of these directives:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ users.php?id=$1    [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Now, a request for `/users/Username` will be caught by the first rule and correctly routed to `user.php?id=Username`, which will fail to match the second rule block.

(I removed the `NC` flag since you are already checking for `a-zA-Z` in the *pattern*. Unless `/users` could be `/uSeRs` as well?!)